# Disable Werkzeug caching in WSGI server

Tags: python, python-3.x, werkzeug

I'm writing a Python Flask application, and using the Werkzeug `run_simple()` method for my development server. I'm running into a problem where Werkzeug's development web server is caching my HTML5 template files. I have to reload the debugger every time I make changes to my HTML5 templates, which is slowing down my workflow.

**Question**: How can I disable caching in the Werkzeug web server?

#### Project Structure

```
frontend
    static
    templates
        index.html
    app.py
wsgi.py
```

Comment: What kind of templates and how do you render them?

Comment: I'm using the `render_template()` method. They're just simple HTML files in my Flask `templates` folder.

Comment: Why aren't you using `app.run(...,debug=True)`?

Comment: 1) Yep Jinja2. 2) I'm not using `app.run()` because I'm relying on `DispatcherMiddleware` from Werkzeug for application routing.